# Configution "copts" based on compiler (gcc vs clang) in Bazel

Tags: c, gcc, clang, bazel

I have a Bazel-based C project and I want to compile it with both `gcc` and `clang` on Linux. To switch between compilers, I prefix the invocation with `CC=<compiler`, like so:

```
CC=clang bazel build //my-package:my-target
```

This works as expected, except I also invoke a Bazel rule with the `copts` parameter:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "my-target",
    srcs = [
        "my-src.c",
    ],
    copts = [
        "-std=c89",
        "-Wno-unused-label",
        "-Wno-unused-variable",
        "-Wno-unused-but-set-variable",
        "-Wno-misleading-indentation",
    ],
)
```

This works, but I get "unknown warning option" messages from `clang`:

```
warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-unused-but-set-variable'; did you mean '-Wno-unused-const-variable'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]

warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-misleading-indentation'; did you mean '-Wno-binding-in-condition'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]
```

Is it possible to specify `copts` arguments *conditional* on the C compiler used for the specific Bazel invocation?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.bazelrc` file and use the `--config` option.

I use Visual Studio 2019 and GCC 9 to build my code.

My **.bazelrc**:

```
build:vs2019 --cxxopt=/std:c++17

build:gcc9 --cxxopt=-std=c++17
```

**Visual Studio 2019**

Build

```
bazel build --config=vs2019 //...
```

Test

```
bazel test --config=vs2019 //...
```

**gcc**

Build

```
bazel build --config=gcc9 //...
```

Test

```
bazel test --config=gcc9 //...
```

For instance FlatlandRT uses this approach to support different compilers -> see [.bazelrc](https://github.com/Vertexwahn/FlatlandRT/blob/main/devertexwahn/.bazelrc)